# Rendering overlay image in graphic context

Tags: ios, core-graphics, ios7, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

My app lets users take a photo with a camera overlay (working part). Then they can save the image, share it, and so on. I have a method for merging the UIImage coming from the image picker with the UIView overlay.

**It stopped working with iOS 7! I cannot understand why...**

```
- (void)saveUserImageWithOverlay: (UIView*)overlay
{
    UIImage *image = self.userImage;

    CGSize outputImageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;       
    outputImageSize.height -= MENU_BAR_UI_OFFSET;

    CGSize userPhotoImageSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    userPhotoImageSize.height = (image.size.height * userPhotoImageSize.width) / image.size.width;  

    if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outputImageSize, NO, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(outputImageSize);
    }

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetAlpha(context, 0.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, outputImageSize.width, outputImageSize.height));
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(2.0,
                                 ((outputImageSize.height - userPhotoImageSize.height) / 2.0) +2.0,
                                 userPhotoImageSize.width -4.0, 
                                 userPhotoImageSize.height -4.0)];


    [self renderView:overlay inContext:context];

    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.editedImage = screenshot;
}
```

The resulting image only contains the photo (no overlay!). Why?!?
I tried rendering only the overlay. It works.
I tried removing the BLACK rect background. It works.

Why the black rect is hiding the overlay?

Comment: What does your `renderOverlay: inContext:` method?

Comment: It's the overlay view rendering in the graphic context, what's the matter with that?